# Composition of cofibrations is a cofibration

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

> If $i : A \to X$ and $j : X \to Z$ are cofibrations  prove that the composition $j \circ i : A \to Z$ is a cofibration.

Since $i : A \to X$ is a cofibration for any space $Y$, a homotopy $F: A \times I \to Y$ and a map $f :X \to Y$ there exists $\tilde{F}:X \times I \to Y$ such that $$\tilde{F}(i(a),t)=F(a,t).$$

Similarly since $j :X \to Z$ is a cofibration for $G: X\times I \to Y$ and $g : X \to Y$ there exists an extension $\tilde{G}:Z\times I \to  Y$ such that $$\tilde{G}(j(x),t)=G(x,t).$$

Now let $Y$ be any space and $H :A \times I \to Y$ a homotopy and $h : Z \to Y$ a map. I need to construct $\tilde{H}:Z \times I \to Y$ such that $$\tilde{H}(j(i(a)),t)=H(a,t).$$

Can I define $$\tilde{H}(z,t)=\begin{cases}\tilde{F}(z,t), & z\in X \\ \tilde{G}(z,t), & z\in Z\end{cases}?$$ This would satisfy the wanted condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define it using $\tilde{F}$ because $\tilde{F}$ has not been defined (what is $F$? What is $f$? You need to provide these!).

Hint: restrict $h$ so that you *do* get suitable "$F$,$f$" and a suitable $\tilde{F}$ using $i$. Then do it all over again using $j$. Lift one step at a time.

Comment: Aren't $F$ and $f$ arbitary choices in the definition? @FShrike

Comment: @Tim The definition of cofibration is of the form: if you give me $A$, I can give you $B$. You’re trying to talk about some “$B$” even though you never provided an “$A$”, and this is not justified and does not make sense.

Comment: Do you mean that I should first consider $H : A \times I \to Y$ and $h : Z \to Y$ and then look at $h\vert_A$ and $h\vert_X$ seperately? @FShrike

Comment: @Tim $h|_A$ won’t be necessary, but you’ll need to take restrictions to use the cofibration hypothesis on $i,j$ yeah

Comment: So you consider $H : A \times I \to Y$ and $h : Z \to Y$. The restriction to Using that $i : A \to X$ is a cofibration we get that there exists $\tilde{F} : X \times I \to Y$ such that $\tilde{F}(x,0) = h\vert_X(x)$ and $\tilde{F}(i(a),t) = H(a,t)$. For the cofibration $j :X\to Z$ I can do basically the same argument and get existence for $\tilde{G}:Z \times I \to Y$ such that $\tilde{G}(z,0)=h(z)$ and $\tilde{G}(j(a),t)=H(a,t)$.

Should I now consider the piecewise map? @FShrike

Comment: @Tim That’s almost it. Your construction of $\tilde{G}$ isn’t quite right; if we’re going to use the cofibration condition on $j$ we have to choose $\tilde{F}$ as our desired homotopy $X\times I\to Y$ (you wrote $\tilde{G}(j(a),t)=H(a,t)$ which can’t quite be right since $H$ is not defined on all $a\in X$; the point is, to lift off from $X$ to $Z$ we need a homotopy defined on $X$ in the first place and we can only get that via the cofibration condition on $i$; we need this intermediary $\tilde{F}$). Then (cont).

Comment: Then by extending $\tilde{F}$ you get a $\tilde{G}$ *which lifts $h$* (! and this is possible because $\tilde{F}(x,0)=h|_X(x,0)$ by construction of $\tilde{F}$) and that’s what you want as a final answer. No piecewise behaviour at all. It is true by construction that $\tilde{G}(j(i(a)),t)=H(a,t)$.